# Is there a way to scale all polygons up or down?

Tags: layers, scale

I am looking for a way to take a layer and effectively scale and translate all the vector polygons.  Specifically, I am trying to make a miniature map of North American States and Provinces that will geographically overlay a small region, such as a town. For example, I'd like to size the polygons to fit over New York City.  Then I could have an app that let's me know what "State/Province" I am in as I drive around NYC using GPS.  To do the scaling/translating, it would be helpful to use a control, such as the mouse wheel, to scale the layer and drag it until it visually fits the region I'm interested in, but any method would be helpful.  I can probably do it blindly in Java by operating on all the vertices and changing the coordinates, but it would involve a lot of trial and error.  I am wondering if there is a tool in QGIS3 that would help.

Comment: "Operating on all the vertices and changing the coordinates" pretty much describes the needed process, exactly. What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

In edit mode, the "Move Feature" and "Scale Feature" seem to be exactly what I'm looking for.